# Why does this code convert characters into ASCII numbers?

Tags: c++, char, integer, ascii

I have used this code and it works perfectly and simple, but I want to know how it works:

```
char caracter;
int m;

cout << "Ingrese un caracter : ";
cin >> caracter;
m = (int)caracter; 

cout << m; 
cout << endl; 
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

Comment: what part of the code is confusing you?

Comment: Because an `int` is not a `char`. `char` is handled differently by `<<`

Comment: Characters are really just numbers with a special representation when you write them to the screen. If you take a character and stick it into another numeric type that doesn't have this special representation, you'll see the numeric value of the character.

Comment: It works becase output streams like `std::cout` have overloads of `operator<<()`.   The overload for outputting a `char` writes the `char` directly to the output device.  For example, assuming an ASCII character set (which is common in practice, but not guaranteed by the standard),  a `char` with numeric value `10` is output "as is" and recognised by output devices (files, screens) as a line feed character (so the cursor moves down one line on screen) whereas outputting an `int` with numeric value `10` outputs the pair of printable characters `'1'` followed immediately by a `'0'`.